# Alternative to regular list indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have some code which takes the keys and values from a dictionary and for this example prints them in a nested for loop. It works insofar as when each key has a list of values which is true. When a key has an empty list I get an IndexingError 'index list out of range'. What method should I be using to index in this circumstance.

The code has 5 lines to generate the test dictionary, it fails when I use the test lines 2,3,4 - 5 is ok.

The keys cannot change in value, they are used elsewhere in the bigger code.

**Code**

```
# TEST LINES
user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[]}

lines_to_test = [k for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
holes_to_test = [v for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
print("lines_to_test : ", lines_to_test )

holes_to_test = [v for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
print("holes_to_test : ", holes_to_test )


for test_row in lines_to_test:
    print("test_row : ", test_row)
    print("    holes to test : ", holes_to_test[test_row - 1])
```

**Returns**

```
lines_to_test :  [1, 2, 3]
holes_to_test :  [[1, 2, 3], [501, 555, 999], [1111, 1002, 1499, 1500]]
test_row :  1
    holes to test :  [1, 2, 3]
test_row :  2
    holes to test :  [501, 555, 999]
test_row :  3
    holes to test :  [1111, 1002, 1499, 1500]
```

**Failing for list index error when using these test lines**

```
#user_return_dict = {1:[], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[], 3:[1111, 1002, 1499, 1500], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
#user_return_dict = {1:[1, 2, 3], 2:[501, 555, 999], 3:[], 4:[1501, 1999, 2000]}
```

**Traceback**

```
The script terminated with an unhandled error.
IndexError: list index out of range ... line 18 # the last line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this bro

```
lines_to_test = [k for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
holes_to_test = [v for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
print("lines_to_test : ", lines_to_test )

holes_to_test = [v for k,v in user_return_dict.items() if v]
print("holes_to_test : ", holes_to_test )

for i, test_row in enumerate(lines_to_test):
    print("test_row : ", test_row)
    print("holes to test : ", holes_to_test[i])
```

Comment: I can see this works perfectly but I don't understand how. In your for loop the "I" and "test_row" how does it know to pick the right index?

Comment: in response to previous @Windy71, by your loop header `for test_row in lines_to_test` 
the key values were affected to test_row. Thus the error. 
In @sarat ravi's answer loop header `for i, test_row in enumerate(lines_to_test)` the index and the key value of each list element are affected to i, test_row.  In the loop, the fist print statement print the key and the second print statement print the value after getting it.